# Adding items by keeping the order vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the bellow list, where I should add items in column B in each sheet ; liste_lameM1, liste_lameM2, liste_lameM3 et liste_lameM4:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDhDY.jpg)

I need to set a condition on the numbers of the column A, to add new item I need to specify the model from a combobox where i have 4 options( M1, M2, M3, M4) to choose the sheet where the item should be added (this part works well).
The second condition is to select a number from 001 to 300 from a combobox to be able to add my item in the correct place on column B, so if I choose 006, modele M1 my data should be in column B, line 7 in worksheet liste_lameM1, if I choose 007, modele M1 my data should be in column B line8 worksheet liste_lameM1, if I choose 010 , modele M2, my data is added on column B line 11 worksheet liste_lameM2 and so on.
here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fin_liste As Range, ligne As Long, ws_lame As Worksheet, ctrl As Boolean
Set ws_lame = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste_Lame_" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value)
Set fin_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste_Lame_" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For j = 2 To fin_liste
    If ws_lame.Range("A" & j) = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value Then
        ctrl = True
        fin_liste = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Mois.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Annee.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Const.Value
Exit For
    End If
Next
If ctrl = False Then
    j = fin_liste + 1
    ws_lame.Range("A" & j).Value = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value
    fin_liste = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Mois.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Annee.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Const.Value
End If
End Sub
```

The problem with my code is that it is not respecting the numbers I am choosing, it just adds the items one after the other, what editing should I make ? thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code? you have a `For` loop that is comparing `Variant` data type `j` (as you haven't declared `j`, by default it will be set as `Variant`) to a `Range` data type. Even if `j` was `Long` data type, `fin_liste` is an object (`Range` data type). Try stepping through and see what happens when you get the `For` loop

Answer (score 0):

> Variable "**j**" for looping, I change to "**ligne**".

Based on your explanation, you can't make the second condition if you use this code as I give you before.

`fin_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(combo.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

So even you choose number between 001 & 300, it still add the data exactly on the last row at column "**B**".
For example, if the last data on cell "**B3**" (B4 still empty) then you choose number 5 (you hope the data will add on "**B6**"), the data will add on "**B4**".

Then maybe you'll find that you can change the `.offset(ComboBox_Num.Value, 0)`, but it will make your data in a mess.
So the code that I give you before ineffective for the 2nd condition.

Based on the 2nd condition, you can use this.

`fin_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(combo.Value).Cells(ComboBox_Num.Value, "B").offset(1, 0)`

I still write `.offset(1, 0)`, because I think you want to add the first data on cell "B2", right?
Actually that code have a problem, but based on you question, I think that problem will not affect you. You'll find it out soon. (You should consider Zac's comment)

I've rewrite your code so I can try it on my excel easier. You can change it into your version.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim fin_liste As Range, ligne As Long, ws_lame As Worksheet, ctrl As Boolean
Set ws_lame = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(combo.value)
Set fin_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(combo.Value).Cells(combo2.Value, "B").Offset(1, 0) '.End(xlUp).Offset(combo2.Value, 0)
For ligne = 2 To fin_liste
    If ws_lame.Range("A" & ligne) = combo2.Value Then
        ctrl = True
        fin_liste = text.Value
    End If
Next

If ctrl = False Then
    ligne = fin_liste + 1
    ws_lame.Range("A" & ligne) = combo2.Value
    fin_liste = text.Value
End If

End Sub
```